# From a static dictionary of strings, infer a type/interface describing the dictionary precisely, using string literals for value types

Tags: typescript, dictionary, type-inference, mapped-types

I have a static dictionary:

```
const myDict = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two"
}
```

The default inferred type for this is `Record<1 | 2, string>`.

I would like to derive a type that only accepts the exact string literals assigned to `myDict` properties:

```
type T = {
  1: typeof "one",
  2: typeof "two"
}
```

How can I derive such type? Typing the original dictionary (so `typeof myDict` would equal to my desired type) would work the best for me.

---

I know I can assert the type via `as` keyword:

```
const myDict = {
  1: "one" as typeof "one",
  2: "two" as typeof "two"
}
```

but this workaround is very impractical and prone to error with large dictionaries. What would be a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
const myDict = {
  1: "one",
  2: "two",
} as const
```